# Calculate the average of an array with a recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion, average

How would you write a recursive function that calculates the average of the elements of an array?

Here's what I have so far:

```
int media(int numeros[], int i, int n) {
    if (i == n-1) return numeros[i]/n;  
    return numeros[i]/n + media(numeros, i + 1, n); 
}
```

But it doesn't work, and I think it's because of the line: `if (i == n-1) return numeros[i]/n;`

Comment: The average of a 1 item array is just the value of the item. Your formula for combining the average of the remaining value with the current item is wrong too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
double media(int numeros[], int i, int n) {
    if (i == n - 1) {
        return numeros[i];
    }

    if (i == 0)
        return ((numeros[i] + media(numeros, i + 1, n)) / n);
    else
        return (numeros[i] + media(numeros, i + 1, n));
}
```

What you're doing is dividing by the number of elements each call - doing that will give you the incorrect average.  The code above does what you were doing, but as its about to return the result (when `i==0`) it'll calculate the actual average based on the total of all the elements

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you divide each element, because of rounding (to integer), you'll quite probably get an incorrect answer (integer divide by integer returns integer).

For `{1,2,3,4}`, we'll divide each element by 4 - `1/4 + 2/4 + 3/4 + 4/4`, but each division returns an integer, so all of them are 0 and the result is 0.

So, **either make it `double`:** (but it's still better to also divide at the end, because of rounding)

```
double media(int numeros[], int i, int n){
   if (i == n-1) return 1.0*numeros[i-1]/n;  
   return 1.0*numeros[i]/n + media(numeros, i + 1, n); 
}
```

Or **divide at the end:** (either the way Sean Landsman suggested, or like below)

```
int media(int numeros[], int i, int n){
   if (i == -1) return media(numeros, 0, n)/n;
   if (i == n-1) return numeros[i-1];
   return numeros[i] + media(numeros, i + 1, n);
}
```

Caller:

```
int media(array, -1, n);
```